# A place to learn OS X 10.5

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-leopard

I borrowed a MacBook. I'd like to find a place to learn the OS X 10.5 interface and keyboard shortcuts. I've been "a PC" forever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.apple.com/support/switch101/

Comment: LOL as I write this comment your rep is 101

Comment: And http://www.apple.com/findouthow And after having used it for a while: http://store.apple.com ;-)

Comment: Free tuition at the Apple Store, too.

Answer (score 2):

A dead-tree book might be a good place to start. I imagine Pogue’s “Switching to Mac: The Missing Manual” is well-done and there are Leopard and Snow Leopard editions.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.lynda.com is a great resource for video tutorials. It is a for-pay site. They have a wealth of content, not just on the OS, but also on the iLife apps.